# While Loop not stopping once condition is met in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, while-loop

I'm trying to have this code iterate until two cells are equal in value. However, the code will loop endlessly even after the two cells equal in value.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var diff = ss.getRange("Q2").getValue();
  var goal = ss.getRange("R1").getValue();

  while (diff != goal) {
    var lr = ss.getLastRow();
    var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(4, 18, lr - 3);
    ss.getRange("R4").setFormula("=IF(Q4*(1+Q$2)>$D$1,$D$1,Q4*(1+Q$2))");
    ss.getRange("R4").copyTo(fillDownRange);

    var source = ss.getRange("Rebalance!R4:R503");
    var destRange = ss.getRange("Rebalance!Q4:Q503");

    source.copyTo(destRange, {
      contentsOnly: true
    });
    source.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a console.log({diff,goal}); to see if the condition is true for a given value

Comment: You never change the value of diff and goal, why wouldn't it run endlessly? They are never equal in value, hence why it continues running.

Comment: @ZouhairDre thank you!! with that info I am able to tell that the variables (since they are rounded). I am just unsure how to define parameters so that the loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  while (ss.getRange("Q2").getValue() != ss.getRange("R1").getValue()) {
    var lr = ss.getLastRow();
    var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(4, 18, lr - 3);
    ss.getRange("R4").setFormula("=IF(Q4*(1+Q$2)>$D$1,$D$1,Q4*(1+Q$2))");
    ss.getRange("R4").copyTo(fillDownRange);
    var source = ss.getRange("Rebalance!R4:R503");
    var destRange = ss.getRange("Rebalance!Q4:Q503");
    source.copyTo(destRange, { contentsOnly: true });
    source.clear();
  }
}
```

or perhaps this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var diff = ss.getRange("Q2").getValue();
  var goal = ss.getRange("R1").getValue();
  while (diff != goal) {
    let lr = ss.getLastRow();
    let fillDownRange = ss.getRange(4, 18, lr - 3);
    ss.getRange("R4").setFormula("=IF(Q4*(1+Q$2)>$D$1,$D$1,Q4*(1+Q$2))");
    ss.getRange("R4").copyTo(fillDownRange);
    let source = ss.getRange("Rebalance!R4:R503");
    let destRange = ss.getRange("Rebalance!Q4:Q503");
    source.copyTo(destRange, { contentsOnly: true });
    source.clear();
    diff = ss.getRange("Q2").getValue();
    goal = ss.getRange("R1").getValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what's wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: You're also making it harder for everyone else trying to adapt this solution to similar problems. They shouldn't all have to figure out what changed and why.

Comment: @Cooper - I tired this (aka defining the variable inside of the parameters of the loop) and it still does work but I'm coming to the conclusion that the values to exactly match (down to the decimal place). Is there a way to round or a better method to get the loop to end?

Comment: What specifically did you try?

Comment: @Cooper that second iteration worked! thank you!!!! :)